# AutoMapper Giving Error, While Mapping A Table That Contains A List. C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

TLDR - The error is:
`The query has been configured to use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery' and contains a collection in the 'Select' call, which could not be split into separate query. Please remove 'AsSplitQuery' if applied or add 'AsSingleQuery' to the query.`

I am developing a backend with EntityFrameworkCore in C#.

My table classes are like this:

```
public class MainTable : BasicAggregateRoot<int>
    {
        public MainTable()
        {
            this.Operations = new HashSet<OperationTable>();
        }


        public long? RecId { get; set; }
        public int FormStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OperationTable> Operations { get; set; }
}
public class OperationTable : BasicAggregateRoot<int>
    {
        public OperationTable()
        {
            this.Works = new HashSet<Work>(); //Not important things
            this.Materials = new HashSet<Material>(); //Not important things
        }

        public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    }
```

And my DTOs are like this:

```
public class MainDto : EntityDto<int>
    {
        public long? RecId { get; set; }
        public int FormStatus { get; set; }
        public List<OperationDto> Operations { get; set; }
    }
public class OperationDto
    {
       public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    }
```

I created maps this way:

```
CreateMap<MainTable, MainDto>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<OperationTable, OperationDto>().ReverseMap();
```

When I commit the mapping by:

```
class Service{     
    
    IRepository<MainTable, int> _mainTableRepository;

    Service(IRepository<MainTable, int> mainTableRepository){
         _mainTableRepository = mainTableRepository;
    }

    List<MainDto> All()
    {
        var result = mainTableRepository.Include(p => p.Operations)
           .ProjectTo<MainDto>(ObjectMapper.GetMapper().ConfigurationProvider)  //Here is the problem.
           .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get the error on the top.

When I get rid of the List from mainDto, error does not occur, but I don't have the result that I want either.
What might be the problem? I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that source you can find the differences between single and split query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

The problem is (I guess) `IRepository.Include` uses split query by default. But (again I guess) AutoMapper is not configured to use split query, it works with single queries.
We need to change the query type before mapping like this:

```
var result = mainTableRepository.Include(p => p.Operations)
        .AsSingleQuery()                         //This solved the problem
        .ProjectTo<MainDto>(ObjectMapper.GetMapper().ConfigurationProvider) 
       .ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need `Include` with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: It's obvious from exception. EF Core do not support `Split Query` with Custom projection via `Select`. It is what AutoMapper generates when you call `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Please don't look down at people and try to help @SvyatoslavDanyliv . The error is ambigious, I didn't use `Select` or `Split Query` in anywhere in my code, I didn't know split query even existed. Can you share the sources for what you told?  `EF Core do not support Split Query` and `AutoMapper generates Select call`

Comment: I know how AutoMapper's `ProjectTo` works. There is no room to discussion, it dynamically generates `Select`. Check [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) - `... to emit a select`

Comment: Looks like in EF Core 6 it is [fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21234)